# Is there a way to add a custom "Visual & Experience Tags" in label studio?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, label-studio

I read the documentation of label studio and I understood that there are 3 types of tags which are: (Object tags, control tags, and Visual & Experience Tags)
Now I want to make a custom tag which will be a check box to filter the labels according to the  selected choice. and this lies under the 3rd type (Visual & Experience Tags). How to create a custom tag to do this?
I'm using this version: https://github.com/HumanSignal/label-studio

I can't find the directory that has the implementation of the tags.

Comment: Create a new React component file within label_studio/frontend/src/tags.
. Register the component in label_studio/frontend/src/tags/index.js.
. Add the tag to your labelling configuration (config.xml).
. Handle checkbox values in your backend code.

Comment: But there is no directory called 'tags' under 'src' in the repo that I mentioned: https://github.com/HumanSignal/label-studio

Comment: It's here now: https://github.com/HumanSignal/label-studio/tree/develop/web/libs/editor/src/tags